# Create playerdata for a fake player in a Minecraft plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm struggling with creating new playerdata (the server's one in /world/playerdata/[uuid].dat). I write a plugin which should make fake players to be banks (but in fact regular fake players) and hold money (I use [Vault API](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/vault.34315/)).

I use Paper 1.17.1 as my dependency.

I thought that this one would do its job:

```
  PlayerProfile profile = Bukkit.createProfile(UUID.randomUUID(), bankName);
```

However no playerdata is created and if I try to check if this player exists in game, it says that it can't find it. I also use [CMI](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/cmi-298-commands-insane-kits-portals-essentials-economy-mysql-sqlite-much-more.3742/) plugin and I would like the solution that is compatible with this (I mean that this new player will be instantly recognized by it - that it exists).

Is there any method to create a [uuid].dat file? Or should I write my custom method, and if so, how should  I start with that?

I would be grateful for any hints on that, since I've been looking for a solution for a quite lot of time and that's one of the last things I need in my plugin to be usable. Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
I don't mean to spawn them, just to use them as Vault API balance, since most economy plugins doesn't support Vault Banks feature.

Comment: You just want to make fake players ? There is multiple tutorial such as [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/371114/), [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/269305/), [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/.273677/). You also have [this plugin](https://github.com/KP56/Fake-Players-Spigot-Plugin)

Comment: You have a lot of things to do more than create bukkit profile's such as make it spawn on the world and send packet to players

Comment: @Elikill58 yes, sort of fake players, because I don't need them to spawn, just need them for keeping Vault API balance and that's it.

Comment: Oh ok. But why use fake players just to save Vault money ? Also, maybe you can only use new GUID instead of creating complete player ?

Comment: I need that for plugins like Quickshop Reremake, because I would like my players to be able to setup shops as a bank account, and Quickshop accepts only players as owner and so do a lot of other plugins :( Firstly I stored it in my own db table, but it turned out I have to use Vault

Comment: Why don't use the [Quickshop repo](https://github.com/Ghost-chu/QuickShop-Reremake) to ask how you can do ? Because creating a player like that require multiple action that are clearly not optimized ^^'

Comment: Good idea, I'll ask them too if they see any other solution :) Thanks, but I'm afraid they won't help me but, let's try

Comment: You should use one of the many available bank plugins that already exist rather than try to misuse the functionality of a shop plugin.

Comment: I just want to link the current issue [here](https://github.com/Ghost-chu/QuickShop-Reremake/issues/1510)

Answer (score 0):

Such as explain in [github issue](https://github.com/Ghost-chu/QuickShop-Reremake/issues/1510) :

To create a player bank account, you should use this :

```java
OfflinePlayer bankAccount = Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer("SomeBankPlayer");
net.milkbowl.vault.economy.Economy economy = getSomeEconomy();
if(!economy.hasAccount(bankAccount)
    economy.createPlayerAccount(bankAccount);
```

Also, in V5, QuickShop's dev add `ShopOwnerNameGettingEvent` event, that can help you.